# Zip file corrupted when receiving

Tags: java, php, zip

I have a PHP script which generates a zip file.

The generated zip file opens file when downloaded through browser.

I have made a Java service to test this PHP script is people can receive the zip file in Java code.

When i copy the received code in Java into a zip file, I get a message saying that zip file is corrupt.

Can someone please advise.

Thank you.

PHP CODE

```
 $zip = new ZipArchive();
    $filename = "labels.zip";

    $fileArray = array();
    if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
        exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
    }

    foreach ($labelPaths as $labelPath) {
        $zip->addFile($labelPath);
    }
    $zip->close();

    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].' 200 OK');
    header("Content-Type: application/zip");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\"");
    readfile($filename);
```

JAVA CODE:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class checkservice {

public static void main(String[] args ) {
    excutePost();
}

public static String excutePost() {
    String targetURL = "http://localhost/intellij/trunk/website/main/productlist.php";

    String urlParameters = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><ProcessShipmentRequest><WebAuthenticationDetail></WebAuthenticationDetail><TransactionDetail> <CustomerTransactionId>987531353</CustomerTransactionId></TransactionDetail><RequestedShipment><Hawb>1234444</Hawb><Service>INT</Service><Mawb>1234444</Mawb><Date>31/10/2017</Date><Company>AZZAM</Company><Contact>AZZAM</Contact>"
    +"<Address1>LINE1</Address1><Address2>LINE2</Address2><Address3>LINE3</Address3><Town>STONY BROOK</Town><Country>US</Country><Postcode>11790</Postcode><telephone>123333</telephone><noOfPieces>1</noOfPieces><Weight>1</Weight>"
    +"<DoxNonDox>NDX</DoxNonDox><Description>COMPUTER</Description><Value>1</Value><Weight>1</Weight><Currency>USD</Currency><Agent>DHL</Agent><Notes>JUST A TEST</Notes></RequestedShipment><RequestedShipment><Hawb>1234444</Hawb>"
    +"<Service>INT</Service><Mawb>1234444</Mawb><Date>31/10/2017</Date><Company>AZZAM</Company><Contact>AZZAM</Contact><Address1>LINE1</Address1><Address2>LINE2</Address2><Address3>LINE3</Address3><Town>STONY BROOK</Town>"
    +"<Country>US</Country><Postcode>11790</Postcode><telephone>123333</telephone><noOfPieces>1</noOfPieces><Weight>1</Weight><DoxNonDox>NDX</DoxNonDox><Description>COMPUTER</Description><Value>1</Value><Weight>1</Weight><Currency>USD</Currency>"
    +"<Agent>DHL</Agent><Notes>JUST A TEST</Notes></RequestedShipment><RequestedShipment><Hawb>1234444</Hawb><Service>TIP</Service><Mawb>1234444</Mawb><Date>31/10/2017</Date><Company>AZZAM</Company><Contact>AZZAM</Contact><Address1>LINE1</Address1><Address2>LINE2</Address2><Address3>LINE3</Address3><Town>STONY BROOK</Town>"
    +"<Country>US</Country><Postcode>11790</Postcode><telephone>123456789</telephone><noOfPieces>1</noOfPieces><Weight>1</Weight><DoxNonDox>NDX</DoxNonDox><Description>COMPUTER</Description><Value>1</Value><Weight>1</Weight><Currency>USD</Currency>"
    +"<Agent>DHL</Agent><Notes>JUST A TEST</Notes></RequestedShipment></ProcessShipmentRequest>";

    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        //Create connection
        url = new URL(targetURL);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" +
                Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

        connection.setUseCaches (false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        //Send request
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                connection.getOutputStream ());
        wr.writeBytes (urlParameters);
        wr.flush ();
        wr.close ();

        //Get Response
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }


        rd.close();
        return response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;

    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If it helps i can add the zip file contents here.

Comment: Yes please add and what exactly `$labelPaths` variable contains?.

Comment: Are you trying to read binary data as if it were a text file, or what's that `BufferedReader` doing in your Java code?

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be your issue:

```
    String line;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
```

The above approach is fine for reading off a string from an input stream, but you're reading off the binary data of a ZIP file and treating it as a string. That string then gets printed to the console, and you copy that into a text file - there's a lot of points of failure there!

The process described above will just, realistically, never work.

This will almost certainly fail due to encoding issues at every step of that process if nothing else, and in addition you're inserting \r characters each newline (which is also going to be wrong.)

Instead, you want to just treat the data as bytes, and pump it to a file directly using a byte array as a buffer (rather than a string):

```
try(FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outFile)) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read;
    while ((read = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
}
```